# UE4 UserWidget Button bind with spawning actor in PlayerController

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Hello my fellow coders -
I am in need of an assistance for this problem

I have MyPlayerController.c (.h), MyGameHUD.c (.h) and MainUIWidget.c (.h)

MyGameHUD is custom class default HUD for MyPlayerController in MyGameMode
MainUIWidget is custom class - simple widget with few buttons
MyPlayerController is custom class

I want to spawn actor on MyPlayerController when button on MainUIWidget is pressed

Until now I got only access violations because it seems that UWorld is not accesible from MainUIWidget

MainUIWidget.h

```
UCLASS()
class MY_API UMainUIWidge: public UUserWidget
{
GENERATED_BODY()
void ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName);
     
MyPlayerController* PlayerControllerPtr;

UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BluePrintReadWrite, Category = "Buttons", meta = (BindWidget))
class UButton* Button_1;
};
```

MainUIWidget.cpp

```
UMainUIWidget::UMainUIWidget(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer) : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
  PlayerControllerPtr = Cast<AMyPlayerController>(GetOwningPlayer());
}
void UMainUIWidget::NativeConstruct()
{
  Super::NativeConstruct();
  // Bind delegates here
  Button_1->OnClicked.AddDynamic(this, &UMainUIWidget::SendSignalBuildBuildingBP_Button1);
}
void UMainUIWidget::ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName)
{
  PlayerControllerPtr->ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName);
}  

void UMainUIWidget::SendSignalBuildBuildingBP_Button1()
{
  GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Signal to build!"));
  ConstructBuilding(FString("SmallHouse"));
}
```

MyGameHUD.h

```
class MY_API AMyGameHUD : public AHUD
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
  AMyGameHUD ();
  virtual void Tick(float DeltaSeconds) override;
  virtual void BeginPlay() override;
  virtual void DrawHUD() override;
  void DrawUI();

  UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BluePrintReadWrite, Category = "Widgets")
  TSubclassOf<UUserWidget> UMainUIWidgetClass;
private:
  UMainUIWidget* UMainUIWidget;
```

MyGameHUD.cpp

```
MyGameHUD::MyGameHUD()
{
  PlayerControllerPtr = Cast<AMyPlayerController>(this->GetOwningPlayerController());
}
void MyGameHUD::BeginPlay()
{
  Super::BeginPlay();
  DrawUI();
}
void MyGameHUD::DrawUI()
{
  if (UMainUIWidgetClass)
  {
    UMainUIWidget= CreateWidget<UMainUIWidget>(GetWorld(), UMainUIWidgetClass);
    if (UMainUIWidget)
    {
      UMainUIWidget->AddToViewport();
    }
  }
}
void MyGameHUD::Tick(float DeltaSeconds)
{
  Super::Tick(DeltaSeconds);
}

void MyGameHUD::DrawHUD()
{
  Super::DrawHUD();
}
```

Expected behavior is to:

1. click on button1 in widget
2. Spawn Actor into world from MyPlayerController

Behavior now:

1. click on button1 in widget
2. trigger function in MyPlayerController
3. MyPlayerController->GetWorld() is empty and SpawnActor will crash due to read access violation.

Any ideas please?

EDIT -> added MyPlayerController

MyPlayerController.cpp

```
AMyPlayerController::AMyPlayerController()
{
  DefaultMouseCursor = EMouseCursor::Crosshairs;
  bShowMouseCursor = true;
  bEnableClickEvents = true;
  bEnableMouseOverEvents = true;

// pre-load class for SpawnActor
      static ConstructorHelpers::FClassFinder<BuildingClass> SmallHouseBPClass(TEXT("Reference/To/Blueprint/Class/BP.BP_C"));
      SmallHouseClass = SmallHouseBPClass.Class;

}
void AMyPlayerController::ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName)
{
  if (BuildingName.Compare("SmallHouse") == 0)
  {
    GetWorld()->SpawnActor<BuildingClass>(SmallHouseClass);
  }
}
```

AMyPlayerController.h

```
UCLASS()
class AMyPlayerController : public APlayerController
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    AMyPlayerController ();
    void ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName);

  UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BluePrintReadOnly, Category = "BuildingClasses")
    TSubclassOf<class BuildingClass> SmallHouseClass;
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see some info about `MyPlayerController` to make this a [mre].

Comment: Added important parts from my MyPlayerController

Comment: Try `GetPawn()->GetWorld()->SpawnActor<BuildingClass>(SmallHouseClass);`

Comment: Still same Read access violation on GetWorld(), I read somwhere that GetWorld will return 0 if actor is not spawned in the World... I dunno if it is this situation, widget itself is not spawned in the world but HUD is and widget is part of HUD I suppose

Comment: It's weird to me, because it's the PlayerController which is calling GetWorld, or in the case of my suggestion it's the Pawn the player is controlling. I would expect both of these, or at least the pawn, to be spawned in the world. Are you clicking this button before you hit play or after play?

Comment: clicking on button after play, when everything else is spawned.

yes controller and even pawn are spawned into world so... weird to me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers all.

Problem solved by :

Moving

```
PlayerControllerPtr = Cast<AMyPlayerController>(this->GetOwningPlayer());
```

from widget's constructor to widget's BeginPlay() event.

Comment: Nice! you should consider [self-accepting](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide the exact Crash details.

To me this looks like your attempting to use `GetOwningPlayer()` to cache in `PlayerControllerPtr` of your Widget, however when creating the Widget in `MyGameHUD::DrawUI()` you are not specifying to the Widget what its Owning Player is.

Please call `SetOwningPlayer(PlayerControllerPtr)` on the Widget when you add it to the Viewport so that it knows which Player owns it. This will cause the `GetOwningPlayer()` function to actually return a value.

I suspect that your crash is actually occurring inside this function

```
void UMainUIWidget::ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName)
{
  PlayerControllerPtr->ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName);
}
```

You should always check validity of Pointers before using them, optionally making some sort of log when it does not pass as expected.

```
void UMainUIWidget::ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName)
{
    if(PlayerControllerPtr)
    {
        PlayerControllerPtr->ConstructBuilding(FString BuildingName);
    }
}
```

`GetWorld()` will always be valid when called inside of a PlayerController as it is an AActor and cannot exist without a World.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, I have resolved my problem by moving " PlayerControllerPtr = Cast<AMyPlayerController>(this->GetOwningPlayer());" from constructor into BeginPlay().

Comment: Good catch. Please also consider adjusting your code as I mentioned above as well.